# Android - avoiding parallel run of same service within multiple apps

Tags: android, service, android-library

***Little background:*** I am developing library which uses one background service. There is a hight probability that there will be 2 or more apps implementing the library on the same android phone.

**Q:** Is there any solution to prevent this background service from running if one of the installed apps already launched the service? I basically need only one instance of that bg service running no matter how many apps is implementing the lib with service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So later on I realized that I can list all running services and match the names to service I am interested in. And if it is running then I won't try to launch another one.

```
protected static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass, Context cont) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) cont.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> list = manager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : list) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The method will return true if it finds the service running. Also you can list only specific amount of services using getRunningServiceInfo(x).

Comment: would you tell me what to pass to isMyServiceRunning method in serviseClass?
actually i want to avoid my apk get run on parllel space application.(this is requested in apk security check report)

Comment: You want to pass in YourService.class. or instead of passing service class, you can directly pass in **service.service.getClassName()**